# Accessing a vagrant box through ip

Tags: git, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am following the following tutorial to do an automated deployment to a production server.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks

I am trying to setup a test remote server using vagrant. But i need to set;

```
$ git remote add production demo@server_domain_or_IP:proj
```

where the server_domain_or_ip should be the ip of the vagrant machine and proj is the bare repository which deploys the code.

How can i configure vagrant/git so that this is possible?

I am able to ssh using

```
$ ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set *static IP* from your Vagrantfile, it does work with [public network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html) or [private network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html)

```
config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"
```

or

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

once you have defined the IP and create the user on the instance you will be able to run your git command

To ssh into the vagrant box, you should run `vagrant ssh` only and vagrant will make sure to connect you on the right port/using right credentials, unless you have used a specific box for which the default vagrant key has not been pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code in above answer before posting the question. They asked for a key file while trying to ssh. Though I could ssh, couldn't make the git command work.

What worked for me was setting the private network option with type: "dhcp".
Then if we ssh into the vagrant box we can get an ip by running ifconfig.
using this ip we can login with the command,

```
ssh [pvt-ip]@vagrant
```

which also works in setting git remote. 
(I might have done something wrong when trying out the above cases, thanks anyway @Frédéric Henri)